# AEC-to-WebAssembly compiler in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler, webassembly, aec

Now that my new compiler is capable of compiling programs such as the [Analog Clock in AEC](https://flatassembler.github.io/analogClock.html), I've decided to share the code of that compiler with you, to see what you think about it.
File `compiler.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "TreeNode.cpp"
#include "bitManipulations.cpp"

AssemblyCode convertToInteger32(const TreeNode node,
                                const CompilationContext context) {
  auto originalCode = node.compile(context);
  const AssemblyCode::AssemblyType i32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32,
                                   i64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64,
                                   f32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f32,
                                   f64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f64,
                                   null = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::null;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == null) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
        << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to convert \""
        << node.text
        << "\" to \"Integer32\", which makes no sense. This could be an "
           "internal compiler error, or there could be something semantically "
           "(though not grammatically) very wrong with your program."
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i32)
    return originalCode;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i64)
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i32.wrap_i64\n" + std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)", i32);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f32)
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i32.trunc_f32_s\n" + std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
        i32); // Makes little sense to me (that, when converting to an integer,
              // the decimal part of the number is simply truncated), but that's
              // how it is done in the vast majority of programming languages.
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f64)
    return AssemblyCode("(i32.trunc_f64_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        i32);
  std::cerr << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Internal compiler error, control reached the "
               "end of the \"convertToInteger32\" function!"
            << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

AssemblyCode convertToInteger64(const TreeNode node,
                                const CompilationContext context) {
  auto originalCode = node.compile(context);
  const AssemblyCode::AssemblyType i32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32,
                                   i64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64,
                                   f32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f32,
                                   f64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f64,
                                   null = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::null;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == null) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
        << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to convert \""
        << node.text
        << "\" to \"Integer64\", which makes no sense. This could be an "
           "internal compiler error, or there could be something semantically "
           "(though not grammatically) very wrong with your program."
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i32)
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i64.extend_i32_s\n" + // If you don't put "_s", JavaScript Virtual
                                // Machine is going to interpret the argument as
                                // unsigned, leading to huge positive numbers
                                // instead of negative ones.
            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
        i64);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i64)
    return originalCode;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f32)
    return AssemblyCode("(i64.trunc_f32_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        i64);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f64)
    return AssemblyCode("(i64.trunc_f64_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        i64);
  std::cerr << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Internal compiler error, control reached the "
               "end of the \"convertToInteger64\" function!"
            << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

AssemblyCode convertToDecimal32(const TreeNode node,
                                const CompilationContext context) {
  auto originalCode = node.compile(context);
  const AssemblyCode::AssemblyType i32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32,
                                   i64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64,
                                   f32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f32,
                                   f64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f64,
                                   null = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::null;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == null) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
        << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to convert \""
        << node.text
        << "\" to \"Decimal32\", which makes no sense. This could be an "
           "internal compiler error, or there could be something semantically "
           "(though not grammatically) very wrong with your program."
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i32)
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(f32.convert_i32_s\n" + // Again, those who designed JavaScript Virtual
                                 // Machine had a weird idea that integers
                                 // should be unsigned unless somebody makes
                                 // them explicitly signed via "_s".
            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
        f32);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i64)
    return AssemblyCode("(f32.convert_i64_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        f32);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f32)
    return originalCode;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f64)
    return AssemblyCode("(f32.demote_f64\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        f32);
  std::cerr << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Internal compiler error, control reached the "
               "end of the \"convertToDecimal32\" function!"
            << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

AssemblyCode convertToDecimal64(const TreeNode node,
                                const CompilationContext context) {
  auto originalCode = node.compile(context);
  const AssemblyCode::AssemblyType i32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32,
                                   i64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64,
                                   f32 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f32,
                                   f64 = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::f64,
                                   null = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::null;
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == null) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
        << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to convert \""
        << node.text
        << "\" to \"Decimal64\", which makes no sense. This could be an "
           "internal compiler error, or there could be something semantically "
           "(though not grammatically) very wrong with your program."
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i32)
    return AssemblyCode("(f64.convert_i32_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        f64);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == i64)
    return AssemblyCode("(f64.convert_i64_s\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        f64);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f32)
    return AssemblyCode("(f64.promote_f32\n" +
                            std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)",
                        f64);
  if (originalCode.assemblyType == f64)
    return originalCode;
  std::cerr << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Internal compiler error, control reached the "
               "end of the \"convertToDecimal64\" function!"
            << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

AssemblyCode convertTo(const TreeNode node, const std::string type,
                       const CompilationContext context) {
  if (type == "Character" or type == "Integer16" or type == "Integer32" or
      std::regex_search(
          type,
          std::regex(
              "Pointer$"))) // When, in JavaScript Virtual Machine, you can't
                            // push types of less than 4 bytes (32 bits) onto
                            // the system stack, you need to convert those to
                            // Integer32 (i32). Well, makes slightly more sense
                            // than the way it is in 64-bit x86 assembly, where
                            // you can put 16-bit values and 64-bit values onto
                            // the system stack, but you can't put 32-bit
                            // values.
    return convertToInteger32(node, context);
  if (type == "Integer64")
    return convertToInteger64(node, context);
  if (type == "Decimal32")
    return convertToDecimal32(node, context);
  if (type == "Decimal64")
    return convertToDecimal64(node, context);
  std::cerr << "Line " << node.lineNumber << ", Column " << node.columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to get "
               "the assembly code for converting \""
            << node.text << "\" into the type \"" << type
            << "\", which doesn't make sense. This could be an internal "
               "compiler error, or there could be something semantically "
               "(though not grammatically) very wrong with your program."
            << std::endl;
  exit(-1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

std::string getStrongerType(int, int, std::string,
                            std::string); // When C++ doesn't support function
                                          // hoisting, like JavaScript does.

AssemblyCode TreeNode::compile(CompilationContext context) const {
  std::string typeOfTheCurrentNode = getType(context);
  if (!mappingOfAECTypesToWebAssemblyTypes.count(typeOfTheCurrentNode)) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
        << ", Internal compiler error: The function \"getType\" returned \""
        << typeOfTheCurrentNode
        << "\", which is an invalid name of type. Aborting the compilation!"
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  AssemblyCode::AssemblyType returnType =
      mappingOfAECTypesToWebAssemblyTypes.at(typeOfTheCurrentNode);
  auto iteratorOfTheCurrentFunction =
      std::find_if(context.functions.begin(), context.functions.end(),
                   [=](function someFunction) {
                     return someFunction.name == context.currentFunctionName;
                   });
  if (iteratorOfTheCurrentFunction == context.functions.end()) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
        << ", Internal compiler error: The \"compile(CompilationContext)\" "
           "function was called without setting the current function name, "
           "aborting compilation (or else the compiler will segfault)!"
        << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  function currentFunction = *iteratorOfTheCurrentFunction;
  std::string assembly;
  if (text == "Does" or text == "Then" or text == "Loop" or
      text == "Else") // Blocks of code are stored by the parser as child nodes
                      // of "Does", "Then", "Else" and "Loop".
  {
    if (text != "Does")
      context.stackSizeOfThisScope =
          0; //"TreeRootNode" is supposed to set up the arguments in the scope
             // before passing the recursion onto the "Does" node.
    for (auto childNode : children) {
      if (childNode.text == "Nothing")
        continue;
      else if (basicDataTypeSizes.count(childNode.text)) {
        // Local variables declaration.
        for (TreeNode variableName : childNode.children) {
          if (variableName.text.back() != '[') { // If it's not an array.
            context.localVariables[variableName.text] = 0;
            for (auto &pair : context.localVariables)
              pair.second += basicDataTypeSizes.at(childNode.text);
            context.variableTypes[variableName.text] = childNode.text;
            context.stackSizeOfThisFunction +=
                basicDataTypeSizes.at(childNode.text);
            context.stackSizeOfThisScope +=
                basicDataTypeSizes.at(childNode.text);
            assembly += "(global.set $stack_pointer\n\t(i32.add (global.get "
                        "$stack_pointer) (i32.const " +
                        std::to_string(basicDataTypeSizes.at(childNode.text)) +
                        ")) ;;Allocating the space for the local variable \"" +
                        variableName.text + "\".\n)\n";
            if (variableName.children.size() and
                variableName.children[0].text ==
                    ":=") // Initial assignment to local variables.
            {
              TreeNode assignmentNode = variableName.children[0];
              assignmentNode.children.insert(assignmentNode.children.begin(),
                                             variableName);
              assembly += assignmentNode.compile(context) + "\n";
            }
          } else { // If that's a local array declaration.
            int arraySizeInBytes =
                basicDataTypeSizes.at(childNode.text) *
                variableName.children[0]
                    .interpretAsACompileTimeIntegerConstant();
            context.localVariables[variableName.text] = 0;
            for (auto &pair : context.localVariables)
              pair.second += arraySizeInBytes;
            context.variableTypes[variableName.text] = childNode.text;
            context.stackSizeOfThisFunction += arraySizeInBytes;
            context.stackSizeOfThisScope += arraySizeInBytes;
            assembly += "(global.set $stack_pointer\n\t(i32.add (global.get "
                        "$stack_pointer) (i32.const " +
                        std::to_string(arraySizeInBytes) +
                        ")) ;;Allocating the space for the local array \"" +
                        variableName.text + "\".\n)\n";
            if (variableName.children.size() == 2 and
                variableName.children[1].text == ":=" and
                variableName.children[1].children[0].text ==
                    "{}") // Initial assignments of local arrays.
            {
              TreeNode initialisationList =
                  variableName.children[1].children[0];
              for (unsigned int i = 0; i < initialisationList.children.size();
                   i++) {
                TreeNode element = initialisationList.children[i];
                TreeNode assignmentNode(
                    ":=", variableName.children[1].lineNumber,
                    variableName.children[1].columnNumber);
                TreeNode whereToAssignTheElement(
                    variableName.text, variableName.lineNumber,
                    variableName
                        .columnNumber); // Damn, can you think up a language in
                                        // which writing stuff like this isn't
                                        // as tedious and error-prone as it is
                                        // in C++ or JavaScript? Maybe some
                                        // language in which you can switch
                                        // between a C-like syntax and a
                                        // Lisp-like syntax at will?
                whereToAssignTheElement.children.push_back(TreeNode(
                    std::to_string(i), variableName.children[0].lineNumber,
                    variableName.children[1].columnNumber));
                assignmentNode.children.push_back(whereToAssignTheElement);
                assignmentNode.children.push_back(element);
                assembly += assignmentNode.compile(context) + "\n";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else
        assembly += std::string(childNode.compile(context)) + "\n";
    }
    assembly += "(global.set $stack_pointer (i32.sub (global.get "
                "$stack_pointer) (i32.const " +
                std::to_string(context.stackSizeOfThisScope) + ")))";
  } else if (text.front() == '"')
    assembly += "(i32.const " + std::to_string(context.globalVariables[text]) +
                ") ;;Pointer to " + text;
  else if (context.variableTypes.count(text)) {
    if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Character")
      assembly +=
          "(i32.load8_s\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer16")
      assembly +=
          "(i32.load16_s\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer32" or
             std::regex_search(typeOfTheCurrentNode, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      assembly += "(i32.load\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer64")
      assembly += "(i64.load\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal32")
      assembly += "(f32.load\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal64")
      assembly += "(f64.load\n" + compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Internal compiler error: Compiler got into a forbidden "
                   "state while compiling the token \""
                << text << "\", aborting the compilation!" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
  } else if (text == ":=") {
    TreeNode rightSide;
    if (children[1].text == ":=") { // Expressions such as "a:=b:=0" or similar.
      TreeNode tmp = children[1]; // In case the "compile" changes the TreeNode
                                  // (which the GNU C++ compiler should forbid,
                                  // but apparently doesn't).
      assembly += children[1].compile(context) + "\n";
      rightSide = tmp.children[0];
    } else
      rightSide = children[1];
    assembly += ";;Assigning " + rightSide.getLispExpression() + " to " +
                children[0].getLispExpression() + ".\n";
    if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Character")
      assembly += "(i32.store8\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToInteger32(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer16")
      assembly += "(i32.store16\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToInteger32(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer32" or
             std::regex_search(typeOfTheCurrentNode, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      assembly += "(i32.store\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToInteger32(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer64")
      assembly += "(i64.store\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToInteger64(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal32")
      assembly += "(f32.store\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToDecimal32(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal64")
      assembly += "(f64.store\n" +
                  children[0].compileAPointer(context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                  convertToDecimal64(rightSide, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Internal compiler error: The compiler got into a "
                   "forbidden state while compiling the token \""
                << text << "\", aborting the compilation!" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
  } else if (text == "If") {
    if (children.size() < 2) {
      std::cerr
          << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
          << ", Compiler error: Corrupt AST, the \"If\" node has less than 2 "
             "child nodes. Aborting the compilation (or else we will segfault)!"
          << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children[1].text != "Then") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: Corrupt AST, the second child of the "
                   "\"If\" node isn't named \"Then\". Aborting the compilation "
                   "(or else we will probably segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children.size() >= 3 and children[2].text != "Else") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: Corrupt AST, the third child of the "
                   "\"If\" node is not named \"Else\", aborting the "
                   "compilation (or else we will probably segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    assembly += "(if\n" + convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) +
                "\n\t(then\n" + children[1].compile(context).indentBy(2) +
                "\n\t)" +
                ((children.size() == 3)
                     ? "\n\t(else\n" +
                           children[2].compile(context).indentBy(2) + "\n\t)\n)"
                     : AssemblyCode("\n)"));
  } else if (text == "While") {
    if (children.size() < 2 or children[1].text != "Loop") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: Corrupt AST, aborting (or else we will "
                   "segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    assembly += "(block\n\t(loop\n\t\t(br_if 1\n\t\t\t(i32.eqz\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(4) +
                "\n\t\t\t)\n\t\t)" + children[1].compile(context).indentBy(2) +
                "\n\t\t(br 0)\n\t)\n)";
  } else if (std::regex_match(text,
                              std::regex("(^\\d+$)|(^0x(\\d|[a-f]|[A-F])+$)")))
    assembly += "(i64.const " + text + ")";
  else if (std::regex_match(text, std::regex("^\\d+\\.\\d*$")))
    assembly += "(f64.const " + text + ")";
  else if (text == "Return") {
    if (currentFunction.returnType != "Nothing") {
      if (children.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                  << ", Compiler error: It's not specified what to return from "
                     "a function that's supposed to return \""
                  << currentFunction.returnType
                  << "\", aborting the compilation (or else the compiler will "
                     "segfault)!"
                  << std::endl;
        exit(1);
      }
      TreeNode valueToBeReturned = children[0];
      if (valueToBeReturned.text == ":=") {
        TreeNode tmp =
            valueToBeReturned; // The C++ compiler is supposed to forbid
                               // side-effects in the "compile" method, since
                               // it's declared as "const", but apparently it
                               // doesn't. It seems to me there is some bug both
                               // in my code and in GNU C++ compiler (which is
                               // supposed to warn me about it).
        assembly += valueToBeReturned.compile(context) + "\n";
        valueToBeReturned = tmp.children[0];
      }
      assembly +=
          ";;Setting for returning: " + valueToBeReturned.getLispExpression() +
          "\n";
      assembly += "(local.set $return_value\n";
      assembly +=
          convertTo(valueToBeReturned, currentFunction.returnType, context)
              .indentBy(1) +
          "\n)\n";
    }
    assembly += "(global.set $stack_pointer (i32.sub (global.get "
                "$stack_pointer) (i32.const " +
                std::to_string(context.stackSizeOfThisFunction) +
                "))) ;;Cleaning up the system stack before returning.\n";
    assembly += "(return";
    if (currentFunction.returnType == "Nothing")
      assembly += ")";
    else
      assembly += " (local.get $return_value))";
  } else if (text == "+") {
    std::vector<TreeNode> children =
        this->children; // So that compiler doesn't complain about iter_swap
                        // being called in a constant function.
    if (std::regex_search(children[1].getType(context), std::regex("Pointer$")))
      std::iter_swap(children.begin(), children.begin() + 1);
    std::string firstType = children[0].getType(context);
    std::string secondType = children[1].getType(context);
    if (std::regex_search(
            firstType,
            std::regex(
                "Pointer$"))) // Multiply the second operand by the numbers of
                              // bytes the data type that the pointer points to
                              // takes. That is, be compatible with pointers in
                              // C and C++, rather than with pointers in
                              // Assembly (which allows unaligned access).
      assembly += "(i32.add\n" +
                  std::string(children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1)) +
                  "\n\t(i32.mul (i32.const " +
                  std::to_string(basicDataTypeSizes.at(firstType.substr(
                      0, firstType.size() - std::string("Pointer").size()))) +
                  ")\n" + convertToInteger32(children[1], context).indentBy(2) +
                  "\n\t)\n)";
    else
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
          ".add\n" +
          convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n)";
  } else if (text == "-") {
    std::string firstType = children[0].getType(context);
    std::string secondType = children[1].getType(context);
    if (!std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
        std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$"))) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: What exactly does it mean to subtract a "
                   "pointer from a number? Aborting the compilation!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    } else if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
               std::regex_search(
                   secondType,
                   std::regex("Pointer$"))) // Subtract two pointers as if they
                                            // were two Integer32s.
      assembly += "(i32.sub\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) +
                  "\n" + children[1].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
             !std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      assembly += "(i32.sub\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) +
                  "\n\t(i32.mul (i32.const " +
                  std::to_string(basicDataTypeSizes.at(firstType.substr(
                      0, firstType.size() - std::string("Pointer").size()))) +
                  ")\n" + children[1].compile(context).indentBy(2) +
                  "\n\t\t)\n\t)\n)";
    else
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
          ".sub\n" +
          convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n)";
  } else if (text == "*")
    assembly +=
        "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) + ".mul\n" +
        convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
        "\n" +
        convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
        "\n)";
  else if (text == "/") {
    if (returnType == AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32 or
        returnType == AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64)
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
          ".div_s\n" +
          convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n)";
    else
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
          ".div\n" +
          convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
          "\n)";
  } else if (text == "<" or text == ">") {
    std::string firstType = children[0].getType(context);
    std::string secondType = children[1].getType(context);
    std::string strongerType;
    if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
        std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      strongerType =
          "Integer32"; // Let's allow people to shoot themselves in the foot by
                       // comparing pointers of different types.
    else
      strongerType =
          getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber, firstType, secondType);
    AssemblyCode::AssemblyType assemblyType =
        mappingOfAECTypesToWebAssemblyTypes.at(strongerType);
    if (assemblyType == AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32 or
        assemblyType == AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i64)
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(assemblyType) +
          (text == "<" ? ".lt_s\n" : ".gt_s\n") +
          convertTo(children[0], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else
      assembly +=
          "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(assemblyType) +
          (text == "<" ? ".lt\n" : ".gt\n") +
          convertTo(children[0], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
          convertTo(children[1], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  } else if (text == "=") {
    std::string firstType = children[0].getType(context);
    std::string secondType = children[1].getType(context);
    std::string strongerType;
    if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
        std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      strongerType = "Integer32";
    else
      strongerType =
          getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber, firstType, secondType);
    AssemblyCode::AssemblyType assemblyType =
        mappingOfAECTypesToWebAssemblyTypes.at(strongerType);
    assembly +=
        "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(assemblyType) + ".eq\n" +
        convertTo(children[0], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
        convertTo(children[1], strongerType, context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  } else if (text == "?:")
    assembly +=
        "(if (result " + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
        ")\n" + convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) +
        "\n\t(then\n" +
        convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(2) +
        "\n\t)\n\t(else\n" +
        convertTo(children[2], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(2) +
        "\n\t)\n)";
  else if (text == "not(")
    assembly += "(i32.eqz\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  else if (text == "mod(")
    assembly +=
        "(" + stringRepresentationOfWebAssemblyType.at(returnType) +
        ".rem_s\n" +
        convertTo(children[0], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
        "\n" +
        convertTo(children[1], typeOfTheCurrentNode, context).indentBy(1) +
        "\n)";
  else if (text == "invertBits(")
    assembly += "(i32.xor (i32.const -1)\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  else if (text == "and")
    assembly += "(i32.and\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[1], context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  else if (text == "or")
    assembly += "(i32.or\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(1) + "\n" +
                convertToInteger32(children[1], context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
  else if (text.back() == '(' and
           basicDataTypeSizes.count(
               text.substr(0, text.size() - 1))) // The casting operator.
    assembly +=
        convertTo(children[0], text.substr(0, text.size() - 1), context);
  else if (std::count_if(context.functions.begin(), context.functions.end(),
                         [=](function someFunction) {
                           return someFunction.name == text;
                         })) {
    function functionToBeCalled = *find_if(
        context.functions.begin(), context.functions.end(),
        [=](function someFunction) { return someFunction.name == text; });
    assembly += "(call $" + text.substr(0, text.size() - 1) + "\n";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
      if (i >= functionToBeCalled.argumentTypes.size()) {
        std::cerr
            << "Line " << children[i].lineNumber << ", Column "
            << children[i].columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Too many arguments passed to the function \""
            << text << "\" (it expects "
            << functionToBeCalled.argumentTypes.size()
            << " arguments). Aborting the compilation (or else the compiler "
               "will segfault)!"
            << std::endl;
        exit(1);
      }
      assembly +=
          convertTo(children[i], functionToBeCalled.argumentTypes[i], context)
              .indentBy(1) +
          "\n";
    }
    for (unsigned int i = children.size();
         i < functionToBeCalled.defaultArgumentValues.size(); i++) {
      if (!functionToBeCalled.defaultArgumentValues[i])
        std::cerr
            << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
            << ", Compiler warning: The argument #" << i + 1 << " (called \""
            << functionToBeCalled.argumentNames[i]
            << "\") of the function named \"" << text
            << "\" isn't being passed to that function, nor does it have some "
               "default value. Your program will very likely crash because of "
               "that!"
            << std::endl; // JavaScript doesn't even warn about such errors,
                          // while C++ refuses to compile a program then. I
                          // suppose I should take a middle ground here.
      assembly +=
          convertTo(TreeNode(std::to_string(
                                 functionToBeCalled.defaultArgumentValues[i]),
                             lineNumber, columnNumber),
                    functionToBeCalled.argumentTypes[i], context)
              .indentBy(1);
    }
    assembly += ")";
  } else if (text == "ValueAt(") {
    if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Character")
      assembly +=
          "(i32.load8_s\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer16")
      assembly +=
          "(i32.load16_s\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer32" or
             std::regex_search(typeOfTheCurrentNode, std::regex("Pointer$")))
      assembly +=
          "(i32.load\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Integer64")
      assembly +=
          "(i64.load\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal32")
      assembly +=
          "(f32.load\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else if (typeOfTheCurrentNode == "Decimal64")
      assembly +=
          "(f64.load\n" + children[0].compile(context).indentBy(1) + "\n)";
    else {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Internal compiler error: The compiler got into a "
                   "forbidden state while compiling \"ValueAt\", aborting!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
  } else if (text == "AddressOf(")
    return children[0].compileAPointer(context);
  else {
    std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
              << ", Compiler error: No rule to compile the token \"" << text
              << "\", quitting now!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  return AssemblyCode(assembly, returnType);
}

AssemblyCode TreeNode::compileAPointer(CompilationContext context) const {
  if (text == "ValueAt(")
    return children[0].compile(context);
  if (context.localVariables.count(text) and text.back() != '[')
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i32.sub\n\t(global.get $stack_pointer)\n\t(i32.const " +
            std::to_string(context.localVariables[text]) + ") ;;" + text +
            "\n)",
        AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32);
  if (context.localVariables.count(text) and text.back() == '[') {
    if (children.empty()) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The array \""
                << text.substr(0, text.size() - 1)
                << "\" has no index in the AST. Aborting the compilation, or "
                   "else the compiler will segfault!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i32.add\n\t(i32.sub\n\t\t(global.get "
        "$stack_pointer)\n\t\t(i32.const " +
            std::to_string(context.localVariables[text]) + ") ;;" + text +
            "\n\t)\n\t(i32.mul\n\t\t(i32.const " +
            std::to_string(basicDataTypeSizes.at(getType(context))) + ")\n" +
            std::string(convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(2)) +
            "\n\t)\n)",
        AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32);
  }
  if (context.globalVariables.count(text) and text.back() != '[')
    return AssemblyCode("(i32.const " +
                            std::to_string(context.globalVariables[text]) +
                            ") ;;" + text,
                        AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32);
  if (context.globalVariables.count(text) and text.back() == '[') {
    if (children.empty()) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The array \""
                << text.substr(0, text.size() - 1)
                << "\" has no index in the AST. Aborting the compilation, or "
                   "else the compiler will segfault!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return AssemblyCode(
        "(i32.add\n\t(i32.const " +
            std::to_string(context.globalVariables[text]) + ") ;;" + text +
            "\n\t(i32.mul\n\t\t(i32.const " +
            std::to_string(basicDataTypeSizes.at(getType(context))) + ")\n" +
            std::string(convertToInteger32(children[0], context).indentBy(3)) +
            "\n\t)\n)",
        AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32);
  }
  std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
            << ", Compiler error: Some part of the compiler attempted to get "
               "the assembly of the pointer to \""
            << text
            << "\", which makes no sense. This could be an internal compiler "
               "error, or there could be something semantically (though not "
               "grammatically) very wrong with your program."
            << std::endl;
  exit(1);
  return AssemblyCode("()");
}

std::string getStrongerType(int lineNumber, int columnNumber,
                            std::string firstType, std::string secondType) {
  if (firstType == "Nothing" or secondType == "Nothing") {
    std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
              << ", Compiler error: Can't add, subtract, multiply or divide "
                 "with something of the type \"Nothing\"!";
    exit(1);
  }
  if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
      !std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$")))
    return firstType;
  if (std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
      !std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")))
    return secondType;
  if (std::regex_search(firstType, std::regex("Pointer$")) and
      std::regex_search(secondType, std::regex("Pointer$"))) {
    std::cerr
        << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
        << ", Compiler error: Can't add, multiply or divide two pointers!";
  }
  if (firstType == "Decimal64" or secondType == "Decimal64")
    return "Decimal64";
  if (firstType == "Decimal32" or secondType == "Decimal32")
    return "Decimal32";
  if (firstType == "Integer64" or secondType == "Integer64")
    return "Integer64";
  if (firstType == "Integer32" or secondType == "Integer32")
    return "Integer32";
  if (firstType == "Integer16" or secondType == "Integer16")
    return "Integer16";
  return firstType;
}

std::string TreeNode::getType(CompilationContext context) const {
  if (std::regex_match(text, std::regex("(^\\d+$)|(^0x(\\d|[a-f]|[A-F])+$)")))
    return "Integer64";
  if (std::regex_match(text, std::regex("^\\d+\\.\\d*$")))
    return "Decimal64";
  if (text == "AddressOf(") {
    if (children.empty()) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: \"AddressOf\" is without the argument!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children.size() > 1) {
      std::cerr
          << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
          << ", Compiler error: Can't take the address of multiple variables!"
          << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children[0].getType(context) == "Nothing") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: \"AddressOf\" has an argument of type "
                   "\"Nothing\"!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return children[0].getType(context) + "Pointer";
  }
  if (text == "ValueAt(") {
    if (children.empty()) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: \"ValueAt\" is without the argument!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children.size() > 1) {
      std::cerr
          << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
          << ", Compiler error: Can't dereference multiple variables at once!"
          << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (std::regex_search(children[0].getType(context),
                          std::regex("Pointer$")) == false) {
      std::cerr
          << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
          << ", Compiler error: The argument to \"ValueAt\" is not a pointer!"
          << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return children[0].getType(context).substr(
        0, children[0].getType(context).size() - std::string("Pointer").size());
  }
  if (context.variableTypes.count(text))
    return context.variableTypes[text];
  if (text[0] == '"') {
    std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
              << ", Internal compiler error: A pointer to the string " << text
              << " is being attempted to compile before the string itself has "
                 "been compiled, aborting the compilation!"
              << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (text == "and" or text == "or" or text == "<" or text == ">" or
      text == "=" or text == "not(" or text == "invertBits(") {
    if (children.empty()) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The operator \"" << text
                << "\" has no operands. Aborting the compilation (or else we "
                   "will segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children.size() < 2 and text != "not(" and text != "invertBits(") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The binary operator \"" << text
                << "\" has less than two operands. Aborting the compilation "
                   "(or else we will segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return "Integer32"; // Because "if" and "br_if" in WebAssembly expect a
                        // "i32", so let's adapt to that.
  }
  if (text == "mod(") {
    if (children.size() != 2) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: \"mod(\" operator requires two integer "
                   "arguments!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (std::regex_search(children[0].getType(context),
                          std::regex("^Decimal")) or
        std::regex_search(children[1].getType(context),
                          std::regex("^Decimal"))) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: Unfortunately, WebAssembly (unlike x86 "
                   "assembly) doesn't support computing remaining of division "
                   "of decimal numbers, so we can't support that either "
                   "outside of compile-time constants."
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber,
                           children[0].getType(context),
                           children[1].getType(context));
  }
  if (text == "If" or text == "Then" or text == "Else" or text == "While" or
      text == "Loop" or text == "Does" or
      text == "Return") // Or else the compiler will claim those
                        // tokens are undeclared variables.
    return "Nothing";
  if (std::regex_match(text, std::regex("^(_|[a-z]|[A-Z])\\w*\\[?"))) {
    std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
              << ", Compiler error: The variable name \"" << text
              << "\" is not declared!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (text == "+" or text == "*" or text == "/") {
    if (children.size() != 2) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The binary operator \"" << text
                << "\" doesn't have exactly two operands. Aborting the "
                   "compilation (or else we will segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    return getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber,
                           children[0].getType(context),
                           children[1].getType(context));
  }
  if (text == "-") {
    if (children.size() != 2) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The binary operator \"" << text
                << "\" doesn't have exactly two operands. Aborting the "
                   "compilation (or else we will segfault)!"
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (std::regex_search(children[0].getType(context),
                          std::regex("Pointer$")) and
        std::regex_search(children[1].getType(context), std::regex("Pointer$")))
      return "Integer32"; // Difference between pointers is an integer of the
                          // same size as the pointers (32-bit).
    return getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber,
                           children[0].getType(context),
                           children[1].getType(context));
  }
  if (text == ":=") {
    if (children.size() < 2) {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: The assignment operator \":=\" has less "
                   "than two operands. Aborting the compilation, or else the "
                   "compiler will segfault."
                << std::endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    if (children[1].getType(context) == "Nothing") {
      std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
                << ", Compiler error: Attempting to assign something of the "
                   "type \"Nothing\" to a variable. Aborting the compilation!"
                << std::endl;
    }
    return children[0].getType(context);
  }
  auto potentialFunction =
      std::find_if(context.functions.begin(), context.functions.end(),
                   [=](function fn) { return fn.name == text; });
  if (potentialFunction != context.functions.end())
    return potentialFunction->returnType;
  if (text.back() == '(' and
      basicDataTypeSizes.count(text.substr(0, text.size() - 1))) // Casting
    return text.substr(0, text.size() - 1);
  if (text.back() == '(') {
    std::cerr << "Line " << lineNumber << ", Column " << columnNumber
              << ", Compiler error: Function \"" << text
              << "\" is not declared!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  if (text == "?:")
    return getStrongerType(lineNumber, columnNumber,
                           children[1].getType(context),
                           children[2].getType(context));
  return "Nothing";
}
```

The rest of the code is available [on my GitHub profile](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/tree/31d2ccf802603d61b3b723046649f30500ef96c0), it's about 4'000 lines long, and I don't think most of it is relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to create an alias for an `enum`

I see you are declaring 5 constants, like `i32`, to avoid having to write out a whole `enum` name, like `AssemblyCode::AssemblyType::i32`. In C++20, you can make all `enum` value names directly accessible in a given scope by writing [`using enum AssemblyCode::AssemblyType`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration). However, if you are stuck with C++11, then the next best thing is still use `using`, but then to just declare a short alias for the `enum` type:

```
using AT = AssemblyCode::AssemblyType;
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
if (originalCode.assemblyType == AT::null) {
    ...
}
```

## Prefer `switch` when dealing with `enum`s

Instead of having multiple `if`-statements when checking the value of an `enum` type variable, prefer using `switch`. Apart from resulting in slightly more concise code, the advantage is that the compiler will then check if you covered all the possible values of that `enum`, and if not it will print a warning. This makes it easy to catch mistakes. So:

```
switch (originalCode.assemblyType) {
case AT::null:
    ...;
    break;
case AT::i32:
    return originalCode;
case AT::i64:
    ...
case AT::f32:
    ...
case AT::f64:
    ...
};
```

## How to handle impossible `enum` values

Technically, a variable of an `enum class` type should never have a value that's not one of those listed in the declaration of that `enum class` type. Some compilers will even assume that it can never happen (Clang), but others (GCC) will require you to write some code after the `switch`, else they will warn you that there is a possibility to reach the end of the non-`void` function without a proper `return`.

Instead of calling `exit(-1)` though, call `abort()`. `-1` is not even a proper exit code, [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) is (and it's usually positive `1`). But `exit()` will also call a normal exit from the program,  whereas `abort()` has the benefit of doing an abnormal exit, which can be used to trigger a core dump, or if it's already running inside a debugger, it tells the debugger that a bug happened right there where it was called.

There is no need to call `return` after a function like `exit()` or `abort()`, as the compiler knows that those functions will never return.

## Don't use `std::endl`

Prefer using [`\n` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n). The latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and will only hurt performance. Note that `std::cerr` is already unbuffered, so there is no need to flush anything when writing to it.

## Possibilities to avoid repeating type names

If you have a function that has a well-defined return type, then in the `return` statement you don't have to repeat that type; the compiler already knows what it is you have to return. So instead of:

```
return AssemblyCode("()");
```

You can just write:

```
return "()";
```

And in case you needed to pass multiple arguments to the constructor of `AssemblyCode`, you can use brace notation:

```
return {"i32.wrap_i64\n" + std::string(originalCode.indentBy(1)) + "\n)", AT::i32};
```

## Create a user defined literal for `AssemblyCode`

Since your assembly code is strings, consider adding a [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for `AssemblyCode`. For example:

```
AssemblyCode operator"" _asm(const char *code) {
    return code;
}
```

This way you can write:

```
return {"i32.wrap_i64\n"_asm + originalCode.indentBy(1) + "\n)", AT::i32};
```

## Avoid stringly typed code

Your program already deals a lot with strings, but avoid using them for things where there is a more appropriate type. Consider the parameter `type` of `convertTo()`. It can only have a few possible values. Create an `enum class` for it, just like you did for `AssemblyType`. This makes the code more type safe, allows you to use `switch` which has benefits as mentioned above, and avoids your CPU having to do lots of string comparisons at run time.

## Avoid regular expressions

> “Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.” *Jamie Zawinski*

Regular expressions can be very powerful, but there are many string parsing problems where they are not the right tool. In particular, it's easy to make mistakes, and they can actually have bad performance. If you want to check if a string ends with some text, then in C++20 you would use [`ends_with()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with):

```
if (... or type.ends_with("Pointer"))
```

If you need to support earlier versions of C++, it is quite easy to implement `ends_with()` yourself without needing regular expressions. Or if you would use an `enum class` for `type`, you wouldn't need to deal with strings to begin with.

There are other regular expressions you are using, like the ones for checking if something is a literal integer or floating point value. However, I can already see they are wrong; they don't allow negative values and they don't allow scientific notation. Doing this properly quickly results in huge regular expressions, but there is a much simpler solution: use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoi) and [`std::stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (or if you can use C++17, [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) is preferred). These functions try to convert a string to `int` or `float`, and you can check whether they succeeded.

## Create more helper functions

There is quite a lot of code duplication that can be avoided by writing more helper functions. You repeated the code to check if something is a pointer by writing out the whole `std::regex()` call. This is a lot of typing, is hard to read, and if you ever change something in how you represent pointer types, you now have to change a lot of code. Consider writing something like:

```
bool is_pointer(const char *type) {
    ...
}
```

Note that if you move from a stringly typed `type` to an `enum class`, having such a helper function would make that transitions a lot easier.

You could also create a function (or macro if you want to print line and function numbers and can't use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) yet) for internal compiler errors, so you could write:

```
if (value != valid) {
    ICE("The function foobar() was called with an invalid value");
}
```

And if you see that `ICE()` is always called like that within an `if`-statement, you could make an `assert()`-like function:

```
compiler_assert(value == valid, "The function foobar() was called with an invalid value");
```